# Stanford NLP sentiment prediction bug; differs from live demo

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I wanted to find a sentiment for the following sentence (tweet):

> After today's turnaround by #Boeing , the $SPX is heading for the best weekly gain since November led by #tech stocks that are flying!

Some experimenting with NLP sentiment predictions lead me to the following code:

```
val pipeline = {
  val props = new Properties()
  props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment")
  props.setProperty("outputFormat", "json")
  new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
}
val text = "After today's turnaround by #Boeing , the $SPX is heading for the best weekly gain since November led by #tech stocks that are flying!"
val annotation: Annotation = pipeline.process(text)
val sentences = annotation.get(classOf[CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation])
pipeline.annotate(annotation)
println(JSONOutputter.jsonPrint(sentences.head.get(classOf[SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree]))
```

which returns negative sentiment contrary to the intuitions and results from live demo http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html (positive with 40% probability).

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the Sentiment Tree returned by standard the tokens are not lamatized but you are using lamatizer in your pipeline. Can you try dropping lamatizer in your pipeline and check .

Comment: Removing  pos, lemma does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemmatizer is an normally optional in a typical NLP pipeline. One has to do extrinsic/intrinsic evaluation with and without various components in the pipeline. Try dropping lemmatizer and adding NER